What is the connection between $P(X>\lambda)$ and $f(\lambda)\lambda$?
Assume you have a positive random variable. It can then be shown that $E[X]=\int_0^\infty P(X>\lambda)d\lambda.$
Proof:
$\int_0^\infty P(X>\lambda)d\lambda=\int_0^\infty E[1_{\{\lambda<X\}}]d\lambda=_{Tonelli}E[\int_0^\infty1_{\{\lambda<X\}}d\lambda]=E[\int_0^Xd\lambda]=E[X].$
$\square$
However, let us assume that $X$ has a probability density function $f(x)$. We obviously also have
$E[X]=\int_0^\infty\lambda f(\lambda)d\lambda$.
This means that we have shown that
$\int_0^\infty\lambda f(\lambda)d\lambda=\int_0^\infty P(X>\lambda)d\lambda$.
This suggests that there is supposed to be some connection between $P(X>\lambda)$ and $f(\lambda)\lambda$? But I am not able to see it. Even if integrals are the same, integrands need not be the same, but are they the same in this case a.e.? Or what is the connection?

Using Tonelli's theorem,
$$\int_0^\infty P(X>x)dx = \int_0^\infty \int_x^\infty f(\lambda)d\lambda dx = \int_0^\infty \int_0^\lambda f(\lambda) dx d\lambda =\int_0^\infty \lambda f(\lambda)d\lambda.$$

Thank you, but I showed this in my original post. We have shown that $\int_0^\infty P(X>x)dx =\int_0^\infty \lambda f(\lambda)d\lambda$. My question is then, what can we then say about the connection between $P(X>x)$ and $f(x)x$ without the integrals.

Ok, I don't think you can say much more than $P(X>x)=\int_x^\infty f(\lambda)d\lambda$.

I see, thank you very much.
